# Sails Js use Firebase Waterline Adapter

Tags: node.js, firebase, sails.js

I am developing a [sails js](http://sailsjs.org) application and have used [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) as databse. In sails application there is a config/connection.js file and it has some predefined connection e.g

```
someMysqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'YOUR_MYSQL_SERVER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS',
    user: 'YOUR_MYSQL_USER',
    password: 'YOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD',
    database: 'YOUR_MYSQL_DB'
  }
```

Now I want to know how to use connection for firebase. I already have host,user,password and database but I don't know what will be adaptor. Does any one know , please help me.

Comment: The sails site says that "supported adapters exist for MySQL, MongoDB, PostgreSQL, Redis, and local disk". Firebase is not in the list, so not supported by them. Finding a third-party adapter is off-topic here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Okay, so it can be achieved by third-party adapter. Is there any helping link?

Comment: Unless you are trying to write an adapter and are having trouble with the code, recommending a third-party resource is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-firebase

Comment: @amit-kumar this would be a community adapter, not officially maintained by Sails.js team. It was recently released and is is under development.

Answer (score 0):

[Waterline Firebase Adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-firebase) is already available at NPM and [GitHub](https://github.com/jpventura/sails-firebase).

[MySQL](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql), [MongoDB](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo), [PostgreSQL](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-postgresql), [Redis](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-redis) and [Disk](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-disk) are maintained by [Sails.js team members](http://sailsjs.com/about).

Currently [the adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-firebase) provides only [semantic](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/contributing/adapter-specification.md#semantic-interface) interface is implemented. [Queryable](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/contributing/adapter-specification.md#queryable-interface) and [migratable](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/contributing/adapter-specification.md#migratable-interface) will be released soon.

[Sails.js v1.0](https://gist.github.com/BigstickCarpet/67f2e6cbd43d2245241e) is on the way and a major refactor is planned due changes on Waterline v1.0

Comment: I have used the package [Waterline Firebase Adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-firebase) but it throw error "Invalid PEM formatted message" when I execute the command "sails lift".